# google maps marker strangely stretched issue

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I am experiencing a strange behavior of google maps (see attached image) does anyone know how that could come? Has anyone experienced that before?

[image: after dragging] 
[image: close]
code below

```
<script>
<!--
    var map_geolocation;

    function savePosition_geolocation(point)
    {
        var input = document.getElementById("id_geolocation");
        input.value = point.lat().toFixed(6) + "," + point.lng().toFixed(6);
        map_geolocation.panTo(point);
    }

    function load_geolocation() {
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(50.728632, 9.111587);

        var options = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: point,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            // mapTypeControl: true,
            // navigationControl: true
        };

        map_geolocation = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_geolocation"), options);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map_geolocation,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.728632, 9.111587),
                draggable: true

        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function(mouseEvent) {
            savePosition_geolocation(mouseEvent.latLng);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(map_geolocation, 'click', function(mouseEvent){
            marker.setPosition(mouseEvent.latLng);
            savePosition_geolocation(mouseEvent.latLng);
        });

    }

    $(function() {
        load_geolocation();
    });

//-->
</script>
        <input type="hidden" name="geolocation" value="50.728632,9.111587" id="id_geolocation" /><div id="map_geolocation" style="width: 400px; height: 300px"></div>
```

Comment: i noticed when i remove draggable from MarkerOptions it looks normal

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've seen various forms of stretched tiles and distorted controls, but this is the first time I see stretched markers and shadows. If we're lucky, adding these lines to your CSS or styles will unstretch the map and markers.

```
 #map_geolocation label { width: auto; display:inline; }
 #map_geolocation img { max-height: none; max-width: none; }
```

I tried your attached code and it looks OK the way it is.

Comment: This helped unstretch the pan and zoom controls when I was building a responsive map. Cheers!

Answer (score 9):

Are you using twitter bootstrap?
If so, try to add the following stylesheet.

```
div#map_geolocation img {
  max-width:none;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked like a charm! Forgot that TB messes with the img widths.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you having this issue on the newer version (v3.33+) 2018-2019 of **Google Maps JavaScript API**. I recommend checking this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54140395/8658147 as well.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)