# Resize Google Maps marker icon image

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, image-resizing

When I load an image into the icon property of a marker it displays with its original size, which is a lot bigger than it should be.

I want to resize to the standard to a smaller size. What is the best way to do this?

Code:

```
function addMyPos(latitude,longitude){
  position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude)
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: position,
    map: map,
    icon: "../res/sit_marron.png"
  });
}
```

Answer (score 400, accepted):

If the original size is 100 x 100 and you want to scale it to 50 x 50, use scaledSize instead of Size.

```js
const icon = {
    url: "../res/sit_marron.png", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
};

const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
    map: map,
    icon: icon
});
```

Comment: This is how to do it under API v3.

Comment: `scaledSize` instead of `scale`= love

Comment: Be sure to twiddle with the anchor points to correctly align the icon to the location.

Comment: You don't have to set `anchor` and `origin`, they are optional. `origin` only needs to be used if you using sprite, which I guess in uncommon. And position of `anchor` is by default in the middle of the bottom, because most marker look like that. If you define it to 0,0, then top left corner is the core position. Better to just leave both options away?

Answer (score 77):

**As mentionned in comments, this is the updated solution in favor of Icon object with documentation.**

Use [Icon object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#complex_icons)

```
var icon = {
    url: "../res/sit_marron.png", // url
    scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // scaled size
    origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0) // anchor
};

 posicion = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud)
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: posicion,
  map: map,
  icon: icon
 });
```

Comment: MarkerImage is deprecated: use the icon object instead !

Comment: This does not resize the image, but crops it?

Comment: Use `icon object` and the `scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(h, w)` property on that object

Comment: @SverrirSigmundarson it should be ```new google.maps.Size(w, h)``` NOT h, w

Comment: @RaviRam [Indeed you're right](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Size), thank you for this correction.

Answer (score 23):

[MarkerImage has been deprecated for Icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#convertingToIcon)

> Until version 3.10 of the Google Maps JavaScript API, complex icons
>   were defined as MarkerImage objects. The Icon object literal was added
>   in 3.10, and replaces MarkerImage from version 3.11 onwards. Icon
>   object literals support the same parameters as MarkerImage, allowing
>   you to easily convert a MarkerImage to an Icon by removing the
>   constructor, wrapping the previous parameters in {}'s, and adding the
>   names of each parameter.

Phillippe's code would now be:

```
 var icon = {
     url: "../res/sit_marron.png", // url
     scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(width, height), // size
     origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
     anchor: new google.maps.Point(anchor_left, anchor_top) // anchor 
 };

 position = new google.maps.LatLng(latitud,longitud)
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: position,
  map: map,
  icon: icon
 });
```

Comment: I think this does not resize the image, but crops it.

Comment: You want `scaledSize` rather than `size`.

Comment: Yeah agree with @bbodenmiller, scaledSize might be the one you are looking for. For my project I use scaledSize and that works for me.

    var icon = { url: imageName, scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(8, 12) };

Answer (score 19):

Delete origin and anchor will be more regular picture

```
  var icon = {
        url: "image path", // url
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(50, 50), // size
    };

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long),
  map: map,
  icon: icon
 });
```

Comment: This worked for me! If I tried to set the scaledImage parameter inside the Marker code, it would not work.

Comment: It works! 2021!!!

Answer (score 3):

If you are using vue2-google-maps like me, the code to set the size looks like this:

```
<gmap-marker
  ..
  :icon="{
    ..
    anchor: { x: iconSize, y: iconSize },
    scaledSize: { height: iconSize, width: iconSize },
  }"
>
```

Answer (score 1):

So I just had this same issue, but a little different. I already had the icon as an object as **Philippe Boissonneault** suggests, but I was using an SVG image.

What solved it for me was: 
Switch from an SVG image to a PNG and following **Catherine Nyo** on having an image that is double the size of what you will use.

Answer (score 0):

A complete beginner like myself to the topic may find it harder to implement one of these answers than, if within your control, to **resize the image yourself** with an online editor or a photo editor like Photoshop.

A 500x500 image will appear larger on the map than a 50x50 image.

No programming required.