# Google Maps APIv3 marker corruption when using over 256 SVG markers

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I have a set of google maps presenting geographical data with SVG markers. We use SVG markers in order to programmatically control the colour/details of a marker without the need to curate 100's of marker variations in PNG format.

If we are displaying over 256 SVG markers we are getting corruption.

The first example show correct SVG markers:
[image]

This is the same form with four times the amount of markers and some overlayed:[image]

I am interested to ascertain whether anyone else has seen this SVG corruption when using google SVG map markers and whether there is a fix I can implement to get around this odd bug?

Here is a fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/L1vbex6t/1/
To allow it to work correctly simply change the 257 to 256 on line 10

```
            function map_init() {
                var defaultZoom = 17;
                var allMarkers = new Array();
                var svgSource = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 150" ><path class="st0" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M50,145.5C40.6,131.6,2.5,73.4,2.5,50C2.5,23.8,23.8,2.5,50,2.5S97.5,23.8,97.5,50C97.5,73.4,59.4,131.6,50,145.5z" /><path class="st1" fill="#000000" d="m50 5c24.8 0 45 20.2 45 45 0 19.5-29.4 67.7-45 91.1-15.6-23.4-45-71.6-45-91.1 0-24.8 20.2-45 45-45m0-5c-27.6 0-50 22.4-50 50s50 100 50 100 50-72.4 50-100-22.4-50-50-50z" /><circle class="st2" fill="#ffbf00" cx="50" cy="50" r="27.5" /><path d="m50 25c13.8 0 25 11.2 25 25s-11.2 25-25 25-25-11.2-25-25 11.2-25 25-25m0-5c-16.6 0-30 13.4-30 30s13.4 30 30 30 30-13.4 30-30-13.4-30-30-30z" /></svg>';
                var mapOptions = {
                    zoom: defaultZoom,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);
                for (i = 0; i < 257; i++) {
                        var ranLat = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1)
                        var ranLng = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1)
                        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ranLat,ranLng);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            icon: {
                                scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(36, 36), // scaled size
                                origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
                                anchor: new google.maps.Point(18, 36), // anchor
                                url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgSource)
                            },
                            position:myLatlng,
                            map:map,
                            draggable:false,
                        });
                        allMarkers.push(marker);
                }
                map_zoom();
                function map_zoom (){
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    for(i = 0;i < allMarkers.length;i++) {
                        bounds.extend(allMarkers[i].getPosition());
                    }
                    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
                        map.fitBounds(bounds);
                    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() { 
                        map.setZoom(map.getZoom()-1); 
                        if(map.getZoom() > defaultZoom){
                            map.fitBounds(bounds);
                            map.setZoom(defaultZoom);
                        }
                        if(allMarkers.length == 1) {
                            map.fitBounds(bounds);
                            map.setZoom(defaultZoom);
                        }
                        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener); 
                    });
                };
            }


map_init();
```

Comment: 1) You could [generate *n* number of random markers](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/94uGL/) and 2) You could use `AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk` which is free for use on Stack snippets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related question: [Google Maps API Custom Marker SVG Size and Position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59898381/google-maps-api-custom-marker-svg-size-and-position)

Set `optimized` to `false`.

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#MarkerOptions.optimized):

> **optimized** *optional*
> **Type:  boolean** *optional*
> Optimization enhances performance by rendering many markers as a single static element. This is useful in cases where a large number of markers is required. Read more about [marker optimization](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#optimize).

> [Optimize Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers#optimize)
> Optimization enhances performance by rendering many markers as a single static element. This is useful in cases where a large number of markers is required. By default, the Maps JavaScript API will decide whether a marker will be optimized. When there is a large number of markers, the Maps JavaScript API will attempt to render markers with optimization. Not all Markers can be optimized; in some situations, the Maps JavaScript API may need to render Markers without optimization. Disable optimized rendering for animated GIFs or PNGs, or when each marker must be rendered as a separate DOM element.

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/xjyqz7oa/)

[image: screenshot of 256 markers]

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    icon: {
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(36, 36), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(18, 36), // anchor
        url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgSource)
    },
    position:myLatlng,
    map:map,
    draggable:false,
    optimized: false
});
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function map_init() {
  var defaultZoom = 17;
  var allMarkers = new Array();
  var svgSource = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 150" ><path class="st0" fill="#FFFFFF" d="M50,145.5C40.6,131.6,2.5,73.4,2.5,50C2.5,23.8,23.8,2.5,50,2.5S97.5,23.8,97.5,50C97.5,73.4,59.4,131.6,50,145.5z" /><path class="st1" fill="#000000" d="m50 5c24.8 0 45 20.2 45 45 0 19.5-29.4 67.7-45 91.1-15.6-23.4-45-71.6-45-91.1 0-24.8 20.2-45 45-45m0-5c-27.6 0-50 22.4-50 50s50 100 50 100 50-72.4 50-100-22.4-50-50-50z" /><circle class="st2" fill="#ffbf00" cx="50" cy="50" r="27.5" /><path d="m50 25c13.8 0 25 11.2 25 25s-11.2 25-25 25-25-11.2-25-25 11.2-25 25-25m0-5c-16.6 0-30 13.4-30 30s13.4 30 30 30 30-13.4 30-30-13.4-30-30-30z" /></svg>';
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: defaultZoom,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
  for (i = 0; i < 520; i++) {
    var ranLat = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1)
    var ranLng = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 5) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1)
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(ranLat, ranLng);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon: {
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(36, 36), // scaled size
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0), // origin
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(18, 36), // anchor
        url: 'data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(svgSource)
      },
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      draggable: false,
      optimized: false
    });
    allMarkers.push(marker);
  }
  map_zoom();

  function map_zoom() {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (i = 0; i < allMarkers.length; i++) {
      bounds.extend(allMarkers[i].getPosition());
    }
    map.setCenter(bounds.getCenter());
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    var listener = google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function() {
      map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
      if (map.getZoom() > defaultZoom) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.setZoom(defaultZoom);
      }
      if (allMarkers.length == 1) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.setZoom(defaultZoom);
      }
      google.maps.event.removeListener(listener);
    });
  };
}


map_init();
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very useful information. Interesting that googles 'optimisation' results in stuffing the marker SVG. I am sure this is not optimal in anyone's book